# Count number of level of each specific xml node in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to determine the level of nodes for all entity tags in my xml file in SQL Server:

```
<root>
<Entities>
<Entity Name="E1">
    <Entity Name="E11">
        <Entity Name="E12">
            <Entity Name="E121"/>
            <Entity Name="E122"/>
            <Entity Name="E123"/>
        </Entity>
        <Entity Name="E13"/>
    </Entity>
</Entity>
<Entity Name="E2">
    <Entity Name="E22"/>
</Entity>
</Entities>
</root>
```

I need data returned like this:

```
Name  Level
-----------
E1    1
E11   2
E12   3
E121  4
E122  4
E121  4
E13   3
E2    1
E22   2
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd also suggest a recursive approach, but a generic one. This will travers down the XML *node-by-node* generically (Of course not the attribute `@Name`, this is valid just for your XML).

Attention: Some things might need the handling of namespaces:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
<Entities>
<Entity Name="E1">
    <Entity Name="E11">
        <Entity Name="E12">
            <Entity Name="E121"/>
            <Entity Name="E122"/>
            <Entity Name="E123"/>
        </Entity>
        <Entity Name="E13"/>
    </Entity>
</Entity>
<Entity Name="E2">
    <Entity Name="E22"/>
</Entity>
</Entities>
</root>';

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Step 
          ,a.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS ElementPath
          ,a.value('@Name','nvarchar(max)') AS Content
          ,a.query('./*') AS TheNode
    FROM @xml.nodes('/*') A(a)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.Step +1 
          ,cte.ElementPath + '/' + a.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') 
          ,a.value('@Name','nvarchar(max)')
          ,a.query('./*')
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY TheNode.nodes('*') A(a)
)
SELECT *
      ,TheNode.value('count(//*)','int') CountSubNodes
FROM cte
ORDER BY Content;
```

The `Step` will tell you the answer you are looking for. The count of sub-nodes will be zero when the element is a final leaf-node.

The result

```
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| Step | ElementPath                               | Content | CountSubNodes |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 1    | root                                      | NULL    | 10            |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 2    | root/Entities                             | NULL    | 9             |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 3    | root/Entities/Entity                      | E1      | 6             |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 4    | root/Entities/Entity/Entity               | E11     | 5             |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 5    | root/Entities/Entity/Entity/Entity        | E12     | 3             |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 6    | root/Entities/Entity/Entity/Entity/Entity | E121    | 0             |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 6    | root/Entities/Entity/Entity/Entity/Entity | E122    | 0             |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 6    | root/Entities/Entity/Entity/Entity/Entity | E123    | 0             |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 5    | root/Entities/Entity/Entity/Entity        | E13     | 0             |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 3    | root/Entities/Entity                      | E2      | 1             |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| 4    | root/Entities/Entity/Entity               | E22     | 0             |
+------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! That's all that I need. Both decisions are work good for me: yours and from David Browne. But your is generic and can works with any example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Recursive CTE like this:

```
declare @doc xml = '
<root>
<Entities>
<Entity Name="E1">
    <Entity Name="E11">
        <Entity Name="E12">
            <Entity Name="E121"/>
            <Entity Name="E122"/>
            <Entity Name="E123"/>
        </Entity>
        <Entity Name="E13"/>
    </Entity>
</Entity>
<Entity Name="E2">
    <Entity Name="E22"/>
</Entity>
</Entities>
</root>';

with q as
(
  select r.e.value('@Name','varchar(10)') Name, r.e.query('.') Entity, 1 depth
  from @doc.nodes('/root/Entities/Entity') r(e)
  union all
  select c.e.value('@Name','varchar(10)'), c.e.query('.') Entity, q.depth + 1 depth
  from q
  cross apply q.Entity.nodes('./Entity/Entity') c(e)
)
select Name, depth
from q
order by Name
```

outputs

```
Name       depth
---------- -----------
E1         1
E11        2
E12        3
E121       4
E122       4
E123       4
E13        3
E2         1
E22        2

(9 rows affected)
```

Comment: I do not think, that the OP needs this *hard-coded* to elements called `<Entity>´. I think the question is a rather generic approach...

Comment: Perhaps.  But that's just a matter of changing some of the XPath element names to `*`.